# Why is the code not working as intended? Its intended to get input and then do true/false checks up to 3 times

Tags: python, if-statement, nested

Creating nested conditional statements but when i run this and the first boolean is false, the next input prompt doesn't come up, please help

```
bird_names="magpie pigeon dove"
bird_guess=input("venture a guess about the bird names we have stored: ")
if bird_guess in bird_names==False:
    bird_guess=input("venture a guess about the bird names we have stored: ")
    if bird_guess in bird_names==False:
        bird_guess=input("try again ")
        if bird_guess in bird_names==False:
            print("you're out of tries")
        else:
            print("third time lucky")
    else:
        print("second time lucky")
else:
    print("first time lucky")
```

Comment: could you give an example of how it's not working :)

Answer (score 3):

The issue is [operator chaining](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). `bird_guess in bird_names==False` is evaluated as:

```
(bird_guess in bird_names) and (bird_names == False)
```

Since the second expression always evaluates to `False`, the condition is never satisfied. You can use parentheses to avoid the problem:

```
(bird_guess in bird_names) == False
```

More idiomatic is to use the purpose-built `not in` operator:

```
bird_guess not in bird_names
```